# How Google cloud messaging works?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM in my android application. I just want to know that by which PHP method GCM responds to application. E.g Adding reg. Id of user in PHP method and push the messsage.
So which PHP method GCM do use to push Message.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google server is actually sending the push message to respective devices. The only things which PHP or other web server  does is registering the device id to google apis. This will enable the device to be registered in google cloud messaging.  After that GCM will be sending the messages to devices which are registered.